# Which database architect is best for website/page stats counting

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, mongodb, redis

I have already tried MongoDB and Redis and what i believe ..these databases are only good when you have a good hardware with a cluster offcourse.

My problem is that, I have to calculate few stuff of a video

- Views / Unique Views / Geo Location / Browser / Playtime etc.
- Number of comments
- Number of shares

There is alot of writing, i update data after every hour in my master database, so there is just one read (for each video in every hour). There are around (min) 5000 visitors online every moment on the website and i have to keep its tracking. I was using Redis, redis works great but i am really worried about its persitancy, I have lost around 4 times my data, millions of views reset. Redis is really good but you need to have a cluster so that if one server is down there is always another server to back it up. MongoDB went slow or may be i am not able to use it properly.

My Question is

I can afford 1 stats server right now, just for stats counting.

- 4x SSD , 24 Gig Ram, Dual quad core 2.4 xeon

With this configuration, which Database Model is Best for Stats Counting Considering 1000 writes per second. I won't mind using SQLite. Need a suggestion perhaps. Help me decide.

I will write my code in PHP.

Comment: Here I have decided to go with "Redis", Redis can do alot of writings. On schedule of every hour. aggregated data will be stored in SQL. So if there is a loss, it will not be more than an hour. And this is what I am going to use on my website It has 700K visitors a day and i can safely say Redis works so smooth you will not even notice but you must learn other techniques to save your data properly. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have considered the use of redis only as a queueing server ?

This is how we manage our stats systems : a triggered event write into a redis server and we have a node.js daemon wich check every minutes the new row in this redis and send the whole new row into a "classical" SQL server (in our case, we have two sql server: one for events and stats, and another for notifications system).

The datas into the Sql servers are aggregated during the night by an another node.js script lauched by cron script (aggregation by time: stats of the day, stats of the week, of the month, etc.).

Comment: Thats a wise approach but here I was thinking i could possibly do all aggregation with Redis itself, i basically increment data of around 20 keys each time. As there is no read, Redis handles writing very good. Never thought of using it as queueing server, might give it a chance. How do you find Redis Persistency?

Comment: We don't really care about the redis persistency, if the redis server crash we lost only 1 minutes of datas, so i don't have really good datas on this point, i know the combined usage of RDB and OAF guaranteed a really good persistency of the datas.
For information, our node daemon make a first aggregation of the datas between redis and the Sql server (we use mysql).

Answer (score 0):

I *believe* SQLite will struggle with so many writes. In my opinion Redis was a good choice.

I am not a Redis power user but I've read a bit about it and used it a few times. The persistence problem you face shouldn't happen. Redis has the ability to save data to the disk: either explicity (ie, on command) or every X seconds.

You could then backup the Redis file to an other server, to make sure you won't lose too much. If you save to disk every hour, you won't lose more than 1 hour of data.

Comment: i have set the configurations such that for every 1000 requests, data is saved after every 30 seconds. Still lost it. Recently our data center "while upgrading" had a small power issue. When Redis came back to life. It has lost all of its data. Luckily i had a back up of my  database but Still suggest me how to make its data more secured in terms of saving.

Comment: @ArslanCb I've never tried to make Redist persist data, as it was not needed for my project. However, I've read that it can be good at persisting data. The best link I can come up with is http://redis.io/topics/persistence but I suppose you already take a look at it. Maybe open a new question about Redis persistence if you need specific info / tips: some people with much more experience may help you.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I think we should close our discussion here by choosing a solution which is Redis as front-end and SQL as backend for secure saving.